# create trigger mysql

Tags: mysql

why this is not work?? i want if i'm insert to this table the table in before i'm insert get decrement....

```
CREATE TRIGGER prosesqc2
AFTER INSERT ON quality2
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO stock_barang 
SET  idbarang = NEW.idbarang, 
     lolos_qc_sfl=New.terima, 
     dalam_proses=new.terima
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE lolos_qc_sfl=lolos_qc_sfl+New.terima 
   and dalam_proses=dalam_proses-new.terima;
END
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Please explain how you know it doesn't work.

Comment: In one case, you are using +new.terima; in the other, -new.terima.

Answer (score 0):

> why this is not work??

1. Wrong `and` in UPDATE section, comma needed;
2. The trigger contains single statement, so BEGIN-END block is excess.

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER prosesqc2
   AFTER INSERT ON quality2
   FOR EACH ROW 
   INSERT INTO stock_barang 
       SET  idbarang     = NEW.idbarang, 
            lolos_qc_sfl = NEW.terima, 
            dalam_proses = NEW.terima
   ON DUPLICATE KEY 
   UPDATE lolos_qc_sfl = lolos_qc_sfl + NEW.terima, 
          dalam_proses = dalam_proses - NEW.terima;
   ```